# Hide multiple variables in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

How can i hide multiple variables in jQuery?

Right now i have this :

```
$("#sub-total-value-v").hide();
```

I was trying to do something like this :

```
$("#sub-total-value-v").$("#sub-total-value-v2").$("#sub-total-value-v3").hide();
```

So i want to hide multiple variables in 1 line instead of copy edit and paste this : `$("#sub-total-value-v").hide();` to `$("#sub-total-value-v2").hide();` etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use comma `,` to separate selectors as follow.

```
$("#sub-total-value-v, #sub-total-value-v2, #sub-total-value-v3").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the **[starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** , for this kind of scenario

```
$("[id^=sub-total-value-v]").hide();
```

Comment: Note: This is suitable when OP wants to hide ALL the elements having id starting with `sub-total-value-v`